# Pasar el resultado de una variable a comillas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito pasar el resultado de una variable y que este quede entre comillas.

```
document.getElementById("plano").addEventListener("keyup", blueprintControl);

function blueprintControl(event){

    var id = event.srcElement.getAttribute("id");
    var valor = $('#'+id).val();
    doSearch($(id);
    $(id).html( "<label>"+id+valor+ "</label>" );

}
```

resultado de la variable id = `identificador`

necesito ahora pasar el valor de id para que quede dentro de `""`

id_convertido = `"identificador"`

No sé si esto es posible hacerlo con jQuery o JavaScript. Ya he intentado de todo y no lo he podido lograr.

Comment: Intentaste de todo? Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando lo que intentaste. De esa forma, te pueden responder qué estaba mal, que es mucho más interesante que responderte `id_convertido = '"' + id + '"';`

Comment: Muchas gracias por las observaciones dadas, hasta ahora uso stack overflow entonces no conozco mucho de la norma para formular preguntas pero las tendré en cuenta para próximas consultas, en cuanto a la respuesta dada funciono perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Hay mil formas de hacerlo. Estoy seguro que alguien con más ganas te va a dar una respuesta más completa. Pero insisto, en tu lugar editaría la pregunta mostrando qué intentaste. Más info en [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Creo que mejor te refieres a introducir una variable para concatenarla, si es así te dejo 2 formas, si no te dejaré otra formá más para simplemente añadirle comillas.

```js
var color = "red", p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0],
    color2 = "blue", b = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0];


/* 1º Introducir variable con "+nombrevariable+" , 
   nota: las comillas deben ser igual que las que usas, osea:
   si usaste "a" para meter otra variable usas las mismas comillas,  
   en este caso comillas dobles " a "+var+" ";
     
*/
b.setAttribute("style","background-color: "+color+";"); 

/* 2º Strings literales [ Nuevas con ES6 ] 
Funcionan con: `` y para introducirle variables usas:

  ${var} o además puedes hacer operaciones como ${4+3} o hasta    ejecutar una función !
*/

p.setAttribute("style",`color: ${color2}`);
```

```html
<b>holaaa</b>
<p>Hola</p>
```

Aquí está el método para agregar comillas simples o dobles:

```js
function add(v,w){
 return w === "d" ? `"${v}"` : `'${v}'`;
}

var a = "identificador";
console.log(add(a));
 // Si el segundo parámetro es "d" , serán comillas dobles, de lo contrario no envies el segundo parámetro y seran simples.
```

Comment: Template literals con backticks. El mejor invento desde los huevos revueltos.